# how do i remove the underline under my links?

Tags: css, underline

I can't seem to find how to remove the underline under the links...

```css
.articles {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 625px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.articles-box {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #E3D41F;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 1px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #B3B3B3 1px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: #B3B3B3 1px 1px 1px;
    font-family: Optima,Segoe,"Segoe UI",Candara,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Google works wonders.

Comment: It would not be a bad idea to also show us *the links*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `text-decoration:none;` on the `<a>`

**Css:**

```css
a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: No on the a tag, just as it says. not on a box.. (it doesn't work on `div's` only on text (like p,h1,h2 etc and a)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you appear to be setting the `text-decoration` property correctly, so I would say that either the styles aren't being applied to the elements that you expect them to be (e.g. the class names are spelled incorrectly), or they are being applied and something is overwriting that property at some point.

I would recommend using the browser tools to explore the HTML for the page, find the element that incorrectly has an underline, and examine where it is getting its styles from (I prefer Chrome for this, but most browsers provide something along these lines). If that doesn't make the solution obvious, I'd be happy to help if you can provide more information (such as the HTML for the elements and the surrounding stuff).